# Mainwindow.xaml can not design when open but still drop item from toolbox

Tags: c#, wpf, ribbon-control

Somethings  went  wrong  when  I open `Mainwindow.xaml`.I couldn't  drag, move or  edit control(`button, textbox`,.....).

[Click to see my error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/meSnT.png)

This is what I try to fix it:

•I try to edit by coding, every controls in `designing form` still were changed when I edited by code but could not move or edit by designing

•I also try to drag some controls from toolbox to `designing form`  and it work correctly(every controls could move or edit by designing) but controls appear before still perform.

•Try open `Mainwindow.xaml` by `Blend Visua Studio`

I'm using `WPF`, Design by  `Ribbon- Control`

THANKS!

Answer (score 0):

If you accidentally (or intentionally) engaged the Lock on the controls, that would prevent you from dragging them around.

Go the the Design menu in VS and then Lock then select "Unlock All" and see if that helps.